# Storing a variable inside a concatenate formula

Tags: excel, vba

I've been having some issues making my formula recognize variables

I have 2 different variables inside the formula (SCp and SCf), they both are values from different cells.

The result that I'm looking for is if a certain cell (let's call it A1) has Tubo written in it, it will follow the first line; so it will begin like "SCT ", else if A1 has Envall written in it, it will follow the second route; so the frase will begin like "SCE ". Else, it will be blank.

To make it easier, let's say the cell A1 has "Tubo" written in it.
SCp = 1,
SCf = 5

The rest should go like following. It starts with "SCT ". Places the first variable, which is 1, adds a hyphen, and follows with the next variable, which is 5.

`ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[13] = ""Tubo"",CONCATENATE(""SCT "",""" & SCp & ""","" - "",""" & SCf & """, IF(RC[13] = ""Envall"",CONCATENATE(""SCE "",""" & SCp & ""","" - "",""" & SCf & """,""""))"`

The final result should be "SCT 1 - 5", but I can't figure out the right way to declare SCp and SCf

Answer (score 0):

So, something like this:

```
=IF(A1="TUBO","SCT "&SCp&"-"&SCf,"SCE "&SCp&"-"&SCf)
```

However I only used one if(), but if you need to check for more texts in A1 then you will need top add as needed.

[image]